# React Native - android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, react-native

> In my react native app i am not able to find in which screen the app is getting crashed or getting this error.
>   I am getting the below error report from  crashlytics.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run (PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: 
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:511)
  at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped (IActivityTaskManager.java:4524)
  at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run (PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

This crash is not related to any screen, it is related to application level crash. Somewhere your code is not memory wise optimised. This usually happens when your activity/fragment try to store data and retrieve it in savedinstance bundle but that much memory is not available. Quick solution I can provide is limit the props which you are passing in next screen, it might be that data you're are sending is not properly serialised.
But first check how many of your user are getting this crash, what are those users android version and how much of percent those particular android version are their for you, because it is code level optimisation and it will take sometime for you to resolve it.
Some hint I can give you is, if you're using viewpager somewhere (or some library which on android side uses viewpager) start for there.